# How to bind NSObject<EAAccessoryDelegate> in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I have the following Obj-C .h, what is the correct way to bind?

```
@interface iSmart : NSObject<EAAccessoryDelegate>{
  id<iSmartDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<iSmartDelegate> delegate;
-(id)init;

@end

__________________________________________________________________________________________

@class iSmart;

@protocol iSmartDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) iSmartDidConnect;
-(void) iSmartDidDisconnect;
-(void) cardStatusChanged:(unsigned char)status;

@end

__________________________________________________________________________________________
```

In this moment I have this for the protocol and interface:

```
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]
interface iSmartDelegate
{
    [Export("iSmartDidConnect")]
    void iSmartDidConnect();

    [Export("iSmartDidDisconnect")]
    void iSmartDidDisconnect();

    [Export("cardStatusChanged:")]
    void CardStatusChanged(Byte status);

}


[BaseType (typeof (EAAccessoryDelegate), 
Delegates=new string [] { "WeakDelegate" },
Events=new Type [] { typeof (iSmartDelegate)})]
interface iSmart
{
    //@property(nonatomic, assign) id<iSmartDelegate> delegate;
    [Export("delegate"), NullAllowed]
    NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

    [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
    iSmartDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    //-(id)init;        
    [Export("init")]
    NSObject init();
}
```

I'm getting this error when i try to build the project in Xamarin Studio 
  *Error BI0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com   (BI0000)*

Thanks

Comment: Binding the iSmartDelegate and the EEAccessoryDelegate protocol are 2 different and separated issues

Comment: The EAAccessoryDelegate is a class in the namespace MonoTouch.ExternalAccessory

Comment: the unsigned char to char is probably wrong. Marschal native unsigned char to .NET byte, as .NET char is 2 bytes long (to support unicode)

Comment: the `BI0000` is a generator issue. Could you run the generator with verbosity set to 2 or 3 and report the log ?

Answer (score 4):

Protocols are just inlined in your ApiDefinition, so you implement declare the few methods of `EAAccessoryDelegate` in your iSmart definition:

```
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface iSmart : EAAccessoryDelegate{
    //bind the protocol here
    [Export ("accessoryDidDisconnect:")]
    void AccessoryDidDisconnect (EAAccessory accessory);
}
```

For binding the delegate, look at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/api_design#Delegates

[UPDATE 2013-02-26] your delegate binding looks ok, except for the native `unsigned char` that should be marshalled to .NET `byte` as the .NET `char` type is 2 bytes long to fit unicode characters.

[UPDATE 2013-02-27] Also, as you lately added that to your question, the proper way to bind a constructor is like this (see 3.3 in http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries) :

```
[Export ("init")]
IntPtr Constructor ();
```