# Binding Obj-C interface to mono

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Suppose I have the following Obj-C interface:

```c
@interface SomeClassName : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *webView
    ...
}
```

How do I go about porting the code to Mono? I tried the following and it gives me error on NSXMLParserDelegate and UIWebViewDelegate as not referenced.

```cs
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]

public partial interface name : NSXMLParserDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate

{

... functions ...

}
```

Comment: I wonder why you did not try out Objective Sharpie, http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c and Xamarin has detailed documentation on how to. Removed mono tag as this question is only monotouch related.

Comment: I have used Objective Sharpie and the result is shown exactly above. I have look through many other examples and I do not think NSXMLParserDelegate and UIWebViewDelegate can be inherited that way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070724/how-to-bind-nsobjecteaaccessorydelegate-in-monotouch), you should just inline the protocol methods into your class...

i.e. Declare the members from `NSXmlParserDelegate` and `UIWebViewDelegate` directly inside your interface.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. I should show you the full interface here:

    @interface SomeClassName : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
    {
    UIWebView *webView

    }

I called NSXMLParser inside the .m so it doesn't appear in the .h. Also, what should I include in order to use NSXMLParserDelegate? It says missing references.

Comment: Don't inherit from NSXMLParserDelegate and UIWebViewDelegate. Just declare their methods inline in your implementation.